# Update table from other table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores user-submitted posts in a `posts` table. Users can also "like these posts. The likes are stored in the `likes` table, one row per like, with columns `id`, `user`, and `postid`.

I've now added a column `likes` to the `posts` table. How can I update the `likes` column in the `posts` table for every post, to reflect the amount of likes for that post in the`likes`table?

TIA!

Comment: are those `likes` related to each other? can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version with a subquery

```
UPDATE posts p
   SET likes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE postid = p.postid)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a82/1)**

Comment: This was super simple to understand and worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE posts p
JOIN (SELECT postid, COUNT(*) c
      FROM likes
      GROUP BY postid) l
ON p.id = l.postid
SET p.likes = l.c
```

Comment: I don't think you want to `group by likes.id`, surely it should be `likes.postid`.

Comment: @Thanks. I did that my first time, then I misread the question and changed it.

Comment: No probs, you need to change to `group by postid` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
update posts p
left join
(
select postid, count(*) likes
from likes
group by postid
) l on p.id = l.postid
set p.likes = ifnull(l.likes, 0);
```

Comment: Setting the default value of `posts.likes` to 0 is probably better than using a left join to update all the unliked posts.